# Prove that orthogonal trajectory of family of conics $y^2-x^2+4xy-2cx = 0$ consist of a family of cubics with common asymptote $x+y=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that orthogonal trajectory of family of conics $y^2-x^2+4xy-2cx = 0$ consist of a family of cubics with common asymptote $x+y=0$?

I am solving a differential equation problem. In that i need to find orthogonal trajectory of $y^2-x^2+4xy-2cx = 0$. I got the orthogonal trajectory as $4x^3+y^3+3x^2y=d$. Now how to show that $x+y=0$ is asymptote of $4x^3+y^3=3x^2y=d$.

Pls elaborate on aymptote finding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide both sides of $4x^3+y^3+3x^2y=d$ on $x^3$ and define $u={y\over x}$. You will have $4+u^3+3u={d\over x^3}$. Tending $x\to \infty$ you get $4+u^3+3^u=0$ which has the root $u=-1$. This means that ${y\over x}=-1$ or $x+y=0$ which means that by limiting $x\to \infty$ there will be $y\to -x$ or $x+y\to 0$

Comment: $\frac{y}{x}\to -1$ does not imply, in general, $x+y\to 0$. Consider, for example, $y(x)=-x+1$

Comment: Take $w=x+y$ then, with the same definition of $u$ we have $w={d\over {x^2(4-u+u^2)}}$. While $u\to -1$ and $x\to \infty$ , $w\to 0$